# Parallel execution of Promises with return values

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, promise, bluebird

I want to call the queryDatabase function in parallel for each member in the resellers array, but cannot seem to find a way to do this given each call returns a value in the 'then' section...When I take away the await, the log prints empty because the promises didnt finish, but I believe the await makes it sequential

```
  // TODO: MAKE PARALLEL
  async function findOrgs(resellers) {
    var ao = [];
    for(const rese of resellers) {
      await queryDatabase(rese)
      .then((results) => {
          ao = ao.concat(results.map(re => re._id));
      })
    }
    console.log("done!", ao);
  }
```

Is it possible to make this parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` instead:

```
async function findOrgs(resellers) {
  const idArrs = await Promise.all(resellers.map((rese) => (
    queryDatabase(rese)
      .then(results => results.map(({ _id }) => _id))
  )))
  const ao = [].concat(...idArrs);
  console.log("done!", ao);
}
```